# I want to find $x$ in this mathematical equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, hyperbolic-functions

$$0.5=\dfrac{e^{1+x}-e^{-1-x}}{e^{1+x}+e^{-1-x}}$$

How do you find the value of $x$ in the equation if you allow

Comment: It seems you did not complete your sentence, and it's hard to guess what thought you had about which methods to "allow".  Did you recognize the right hand side as a well-known hyperbolic function?

Comment: Yes it's hyperbolic function

Comment: That said, is it not acceptable to use the inverse hyperbolic function to get $1+x$ (and then subtract $1$ from that value to get $x$)?

Comment: X is threshold  .. unknown value that must be proficient in it and there is no shortage

Comment: I'm referring to the incomplete sentence in your Question, "if you allow ...".  The Question really doesn't make sense the way you left it, and I don't know what to make of the last Comment.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**. one may just set $X=e^{x+1}$ then solve
$$
\frac12=\frac{X-\frac1X}{X+\frac1X}
$$ that is
$$
X^2+1=2\left(X^2-1\right).
$$

Answer (score 4):

$$\tanh x={\frac {e^{x}-e^{-x}}{e^{x}+e^{-x}}}$$
so
$$\tanh (x+1)={\frac {e^{x+1}-e^{-x-1}}{e^{x+1}+e^{-x-1}}}=0.5$$
$$x+1=\tanh^{-1}0.5$$
$$x=\tanh^{-1}0.5-1$$

Comment: That's not much of a hint unless you think that $\operatorname{arctanh}(\frac12)-1$ is a acceptable form for the answer.

Comment: x @EHE, See Olivier's answer. I get something like $\frac12\log3-1$

Answer (score 1):

your equation is equivalent to $$e^{1+x}+\frac{1}{e^{1+x}}=2e^{1+x}-\frac{2}{e^{1+x}}$$ setting $$u=e^{1+x}$$ we get
$$u+1/u=2u+2/u$$
or $$3=u^2$$
can you proceed?